# Webpack-dev-server as a "runner" for tests and eslint?

Tags: gulp, webpack, karma-runner, webpack-dev-server, eslint

I have webpack-dev-server, and I run it from npm (package.jso)n:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --profile --colors --hot"
},
```

It is from some starter kit and it works well. I can run `node run dev` and webpack watches any changes in my files and reloads modules.

That is fine.

But! I've worked with gulp recently and my workflow was:
0. Start `gulp watch`.
1. Make awesome change in any .js file.
2. Gulp runs bundler (browserify), eslint and tests (karma and jasmine on phantomjs) on every change.

Is it possible to achieve that flow with webpack-dev-server? Or should I rather use webpack with "watch" flag as one of tasks in gulp (instead of browserify) and stay with my flow?

I think that I don't really need this hot module reloading thing. I have never worked with that and I was fine (well, it is not very solid argument, but still... :)). It is really that super feature, and I should run webpack-dev-server and maybe gulp tasks in separate terminal window?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use Webpack 2 with its tree-shaking feature with ESLint. You need those for also code quality and acceleration while making development.

The first thing you can choose is using a seperate npm task (in your package.json) buy using ESLint like the following. It will be listening the changing events in your code (declared in the 'test' regex) then linting it:

```
"lint": "eslint <your-path-through-codes>"
```

While it is running in the background, you can continually develop your code and refactor the code again and again.

You can deliver the configuration like the following:

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  configFile: './.eslintrc'
})
```

Comment: Actually, I decided to use npm scripts, and I have script "dev" which runs webpack, tests and linter scripts using "npm-run-all".